# RWD: Line up object outside a table with column inside a table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

At wider screen widths, I have an image to the left of a table, by using `float:left` on the img tag. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
<img>
<table>
<tr><th>This</th><td>Some fairly long content</td></tr>
<tr><th>And the other</th><td>Some fairly long content</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

But at narrower screen widths I want to have the image on top of the table of information, rather than next to it. I do this with a media query to remove the float, then use margin:auto to have it centred. So my CSS is something like this:

```
img {float:left;width:320px;height:240px;padding:1rem;}
@media (max-width: 630px) {
  img {margin:auto;float:none;padding:0;}
  }
```

This works, but my problem is it *looks* wrong to have the image centred (or left-aligned, or right-aligned). I realized what I want is for the left side of the image to line up with the left side of the second table column.

And that has me stumped. I need a solution that works back to IE8. The left column width is not fixed (copywriters can change the row labels at any time).

Answer (score 0):

(This is the compromise solution I went for; perhaps it is the case that what I really wanted to do is impossible?)

I put a `width` on the first column of the table. E.g.

```
th {width:5rem;}
```

Then put padding on the image:

```
img {padding: 0 0 0 5rem;}
```

Not ideal as I didn't want to control the width of that column... but the only downside is if later someone puts a long string in the first column their string will word wrap (which might even be for the best).